# automate manual snapshot of RDS (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, snapshot

Due to compliance requirements, I need a manual snapshot
**strong text** of RDS(postgres).
Looks like, I cannot use Cloudformation for this automation ?
My only option, based upon my research is --
create a shell script ( **using  create-db-snapshot** ) and call the script using cloudwatch ?
Looking for some guidance here ?
Is this the only route or is there a better option ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. Here are the two options:

1. Write a Lambda to use boto3 and create_db_snapshot
2. Use AWS Backup

I am leaning towards AWS Backup as it is much cleaner than writing plenty of code myself. The other benefit of AWS Backup is that it allows to move to another region, set frequency, retention and all the other stuff required for compliance.